# iptable rule to route only outbound traffic through VPN

Tags: iptables, ip

I have a server at `myserver.com` and I want people on the Internet to be able to access that server using its name, but I want all the outgoing traffic that isn't a direct response to incoming traffic to go through VPN.  For example, the server has transmission installed and I want transmission to always go through VPN, but if someone access a webpage on the server the server should not try to respond over the VPN, because obviously that wouldn't make sense.  I set this up once several years ago using some combination iptable rules and routes.  I remember it was only a few lines, but I can't for the life of me remember the exact rules.  I have tried several variations of the rules seen below (found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/391368/142184) and [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/iptables-essentials-common-firewall-rules-and-commands)), but to no avail.

```
sudo iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --sports 80,443,22 -j MARK --set-mark 10
sudo ip route add table 100 default via 192.168.1.1
sudo ip rule add fwmark 10 table 100
sudo ip route flush cache

sudo iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out based on info I found [here](https://forum.linode.com/viewtopic.php?p=50114&sid=b440414422596bb7dbc96cf7c9ee511f#p50114).  For completeness I'll repeat what what was said there:

This is a classic problem.  When you connect your server using its public IP address, the return packets get routed over the VPN. You need to force those packets to be routed over the public Ethernet interface. These rule/route commands should do the trick:

```
ip rule add from x.x.x.x table 128
ip route add table 128 to y.y.y.y/y dev ethX
ip route add table 128 default via z.z.z.z
```

Where `x.x.x.x` is your server's public IP, `y.y.y.y/y` is the subnet of your server's public IP address, `ethX` is your server's public Ethernet interface, and `z.z.z.z` is your default gateway.  For example:

```
ip rule add from 172.16.9.132 table 128
ip route add table 128 to 172.16.9.0/24 dev eth0
ip route add table 128 default via 172.16.9.1
```

It is important to note that the above example makes use of the server's public IP, but since I'm behind a router and all connections into the server are being forwarded from the router I can just use the server's local IP as seen in the example below:

```
ip rule add from 192.168.1.10 table 128
ip route add table 128 to 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0
ip route add table 128 default via 192.168.1.1
```

It is likely you will want these rules to persist after a reboot.  There are several ways that can be done, one such way is to add the rules to your `etc/network/interfaces` file under the appropriate interface as seen below:

```
# Only packets related to connections initiated by this machine should go
# through the VPN.  All other packets should be routed around the VPN.  This
# allows this  machine to be accessed via its public IP, but prevents its
# public IP from being exposed by services like transmission.

up ip rule add from 192.168.1.5 table 128
up ip route add table 128 to 192.168.1.0/24 dev enp4s0
up ip route add table 128 default via 192.168.1.1

down ip route del table 128 default via 192.168.1.1
down ip route del table 128 to 192.168.1.0/24 dev enp4s0
down ip rule del from 192.168.1.5 table 128
```